# SSMS - MiniMap overview

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Does anyone know of a plugin for SSMS that works in a similar way to the 'MiniMap' on Sublime Text? I.e. offers an shrunk-down version of the contents of the query editor, like the one after [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCU3l.jpg):

[image: Click to enlarge] ([Click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jnKF.png))

Also: http://www.sublimetext.com/features

The bar on the left provides an overview of the entire text block, and by clicking and dragging, different sections of the text can be viewed.

It's a really useful tool to have in the text editor, and I was wondering if there was a plugin for SQL Server Management Studio that offers the same functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSMS 2016 now has this feature, you can read more about that [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/new-feature-in-sql-server-management-studio-2016-scroll-bar/). In order to enable the minimap, right click on the scroll bar of a query in SSMS and then click **Scroll Bar Options...**, this will open the window below.

[image: Scroll Bar Options]

As highlighted, you will want to set the Behavior to **Use map mode for vertical scroll bar**, as well as setting any of the other settings, such as showing the preview tooltip.

Comment: Six years plus since the question and MS heard my plea! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

[SSMS Tool Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) has something similar although I must say not as nice... It gives you a query history too which I find invaluable when I forget to save scripts I spent along time tweaking ...

Comment: Thanks for this - not exactly what I needed but some useful things nonetheless

Comment: No Problem, Glad you liked it